# Deny access to all files except index file - Apache2

Tags: linux, apache

I'm configuring an Apache2 server, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to deny access to all files/directories except the index file.

My website resides inside /var/www/

This is my current setup in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file:

```
<Directory />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How do I solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `<FilesMatch>` for index.php. If it doesn't work in this position, move it above the directory's `Deny from all`.  Change `index.html` to whatever your index file is.

```
<Directory />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
  # Deny first, then allow
  Order deny,allow
  # Deny everyone from everything
  Deny from all

  <FilesMatch index\.html>
    # but allow index.html
    Allow from all
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off simply piping everything to the index file, not denying access to everything else.

This can be done through RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
# index goes to index (this is first to prevent infinite loop)
RewriteRule ^/index\.html$ - [L]
# everything else goes to index
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
```